# Git not working properly?

Tags: git

I have a problem with my git repository, and I'm not sure weather the problem is me not using it correctly or if it is some kind of bug ...

I am using git 1.7.9. inside cygwin.

My problem is that I can't see log history of a file (any file). Let's say I want to see history of a file called index.php. I type this:

> git log -p index.php

But there's not response. Git just closes. When I try this:

> git blame index.php

I get "00000000 (Not Committed Yet 2012-05-10 19:27:07 +0200  1)" for every line in that file. But that file WAS commited many time before. Am I doing something wrong or is maybe my git repository corrupt ?

Any ideas are welcome :) Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's output of status and ls-files commands:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

xx77abs@Ferdo ~/gaudeamus_ipad/HTML
$ git ls-files
```

Comment: What does `git status` show?  What does `git ls-files` show?

Comment: @larsks: I've edited the question and added outputs of these commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So to answer my own question ...
First I want to thank larsks, because his asking for git ls-files output gave me idea of what's wrong ...

My git repository is in gaudeamus_ipad folder. Inside that folder, I have folder called HTML. Initially it was called html, but somewhere along I renamed it into HTML. After I've executed "git ls-files" in HTML folder, I got nothing. Then I went one folder up and executed "git ls-files" again. This is part of the output:

```
html/index.php
```

As you can see, here HTML folder is spelled lowercase. I've also noticed that in cygwin I can enter folder HTML by using "cd HTML" and "cd html" commands. But when I enter it using "cd HTML", git isn't working properly. When I enter it using "cd html", git is working as it should. I guess it's some kind of cygwin bug (although I'm not sure if this can be classified as a bug) ...

Anyway, that's how I solved my problem. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Thanks this really helped me. I had the same issue after I changed folder names a few times while messing around with different versions of MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

If your repository isn't to large, you can try deleting and re-cloning into a different location. That seems to fix most problems I encounter.

Comment: It's not really large (30 mb), but I need to preserve all past changes